# How to catch url params contain in a redirect url of an api request

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in API requests and javascript...
An API request give me some params i want to catch but they are in the redirect url generated... how i can catch them ?

Here, my actual code with `"link" = my API request url` :

```js
fetch(link)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

With that, I have only access to the text format of the html response with somewhere

`<html><body><script> var url = THE_URL_OF_REDIRECTION_WITH_PARAMS_I_WANT_TO_CATCH`

Exemple of response :

```html
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Veuillez patienter...</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * Delete cookies (iPlanetDirectoryPro, amlbcookie)
         */
        function removeCookie(cookieName) {
            cookieValue = "";
            cookieLifetime = -1;
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (cookieLifetime*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cookieName+"=" + JSON.stringify(cookieValue) + expires+"; path=/; domain=.ene.fr";
        }
        removeCookie("iPlanetDirectoryPro");
        removeCookie("amlbcookie");

        /**
         * Parse url query
         */
        var parseQueryString = function( queryString ) {
            var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
            // Split into key/value pairs
            queries = queryString.split("&");
            // Convert the array of strings into an object
            for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                temp = queries[i].split('=');
                params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
            }
            return params;
        };
        
        // THE_URL_OF_REDIRECTION_WITH_PARAMS_I_WANT_TO_CATCH :
        var url = "https://gw.hml.api.ene.fr/redirect?code=qhTyG5h6bfdPktWggLidemqFDwkwl2&state=fz80ac780&usage_point_id=56416914714165";

        // Get redirect_uri params
        var queryString            = url.substring( url.indexOf('?') + 1 );
        var params                 = parseQueryString(queryString);
        var forceNonAutomaticClose = params.close !== undefined && params.close == 'false';

        // Avoid closing popup
        if (forceNonAutomaticClose || !this.window.opener || this.window.opener.closed) {
            this.window.location.href = url;
        } else if (this.window.opener && !this.window.opener.closed) {
            // Close popup
            this.window.opener.location.href = url;
            this.window.close();
        }
    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How I can complete my code ?

Thanks !

Comment: Update your question with response

Comment: Why your response is an HTML response instead a JSON response with the values you need?

Comment: If it's not doing a HTTP redirect, but something custom in the page, you'll have a hard time

Comment: I have succeeded in transform the text response into html response with `DOMParser()` and then i can catch the `<script>` tag with `querySelector("script")`... but now, how i can catch the params of the "url" variable ?